# HAISU with a twist

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, mobius-strip

HAISU is a [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzle designed by this site's very own [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper). To quote them:

> HAISU is a portmanteau of three Japanese words - 'hairu', to enter, 'su', number, and 'hausu', an English borrow word meaning house, of course.
>   Together, we get a meaning of 'enter number house', which I have roughly translated to English as 'Room Count'.
>
> The rules are simple - draw a path from the O to the X, passing through every cell in the grid exactly once. The grid is divided into several rooms. When your path passes over a cell with the big number N, it must be the Nth time you have entered the room. If a room has a small number m in the top left corner, you must enter that room a total of m times.

For an example puzzle, see the original post: [HAISU (Room Count): An original grid-logic challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48029/haisu-room-count-an-original-grid-logic-challenge)

This puzzle is a bit different, however: it is embedded on a Möbius strip. The top and bottom act like normal, but the left and right edges join up as shown by the letters. Good luck!

[image: HAISU with a twist]

Notes:

- The letters aren't their own cells, they just tell you where to join the two sides up.
- The rooms do not connect between the two sides of the puzzle (e.g. if an edge passes through *d* it will leave and enter the room again).
- "No guessing, no handwavy steps, just pure logic required to solve this puzzle!" - [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper)
- Thanks [Wen1now](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32642/wen1now) for testsolving!

Comment: Great idea with the Möbius strip :)

Comment: I'm having trouble understandig the big numbers. Aren't they basically the same as the small numbers?

Comment: The small numbers refer to the amount of times you have to enter a room (room = thick lines). The large numbers refer to a cell (small square / thin lines). If a cell contains a large number (`N`), you have to pass over the cell the `N`th time you enter the room that contains your cell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So that should be the solution:

> [image]

---

Step by step:

> 1. Top-Right: Cell with the 2 can't be connected to the `O`.
>  2. Below the `O`: Room has to be entered exactly once -> cells have to be connected to each other.
>  3. Bottom-Left: Only way to hit the 3 on the third entrance since it is next to the `X`.
>  [image]
>
>
>  1. Bottom-Left: Cell only has two free neighbour-cells left.
>  2. Bottom: Cell only has two free neighbour-cells left.
>  3. Top: Room with the 2 must be entered at least two times + the room below can only be entered once -> all cells have to be connected to each other.
>  [image]
>
>
>  1. Top-Right: Connect the Möbius strip.
>  2. Above the `X`: Room has to be entered two times and has two cells -> they can't be connected.
>  3. Next to it: Room has to be entered three times -> top-right cell can't be connected to any other cell in the room.
>  [image]
>
>
>  Now it gets a bit more complicated since we have to consider the direction of the path.
>  1. Bottom-Left: The path on the bottom-left is connected with the top-right. At the top-right the direction of the path is from left to right since we have to pass the 2 on our second entry. Therefore if we would connect the bottom-left path with the `e` or the `f` we would always end at the `O` which would lead to a direction-conflict.
>  2. Top-Right: Since we can't use `e` and `f` any more, this is the only possible path to connect the cells.
>  [image]
>
>
>  1. At the red arrow: The cell can't be connected to his left and his lower neighbour at the same time -> has to be connected to his right neighbour.
>  2. Right: Cell only has two free neighbour-cells left.
>  3. Left: Complete the connection with `d`.
>  [image]
>
>
>  The next step is even more complicated.
>  From now on I will call a move from one side to another (by connecting two letters) a Möbius-Move.
>  Since the puzzle is a square with an nxn amount of cells, we can color it in a black/white chess-pattern (like in the next picture in the top-left quarter).
>  Let's try to connect all cells starting from the top right corner without using a Möbius-Move. You will see that the path will always end in a black cell (for example: top-right quarter in the next picture).
>  Now we do the same thing, but we will use exactly one Möbius-Move. Now the path will always end in a white cell (example: bottom-left quarter).
>  Last but not least we try the same thing again, this time with two Möbius-Moves. And the path will end in a black cell (example: bottom-right quarter).
>
>  The important thing to notice right here is the following:
>  - even number of Möbius-Moves: path will end at the same color
>  - odd number of Möbius-Moves: path will end at the other color
>  
>  [image]
>
>
>  Now let's take a look at the puzzle again:
>  The cells with the `X` and the `O` both have the same color, so we can conclude that we need an even number of Möbius-Moves.
>
>  We already used two Möbius-Moves and there are three letters left that could be connected, so we have to either use two more or no more Möbius-Moves.
>  Take a look at the room in the top-left corner. Since the room has to be entered at least two times and has an odd number of cells, it is not possible to find a solution with no more Möbius-Moves.
>  Now we know that there are exactly two more Möbius-Moves left.
>
>  Let's assume we would do a Möbius-Move at `a` and `c`. As you can see in the image, this leads to a problem in the bottom-right corner.
>  Therefore we now know that there has to be a Möbius-Move at the letter `c`.
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  We already know that we have to enter rooms in the top-left and the bottom-right corner exactly two times.
>  We enter them two times with a Möbius-Move, so we have to leave them two times with a normal move.
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  Now take a look at the cells inside the red frame.
>  There are four path-ends inside the frame. Let's assume we would connect the two paths at `(1)`. Now we would need an additional path going upwards at `(2)`.
>  Now there would be three path-ends at the top-half of the red frame, which would lead to an incomplete path.
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  Knowing that we can't connect the paths at `(1)` these are the only possible steps:
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  Now we just do some basic path-connecting. Not much logic required.
>  
>  [image]
>
>
>  Bottom-Right: The cell with the `2` has to be passed at the second entry.
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  Now to finish the puzzle, we just have to connect the last cells.
>  The only possible way to enter the room with the `6` six times, is by leaving and re-entering it. 
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  **And there we have it: The puzzle is finished :)**

Comment: Nice job! Did you manage to get there with logic?

Comment: Yes, of course. At first it was a bit confusing with the Möbius strip but it's a nice additional challange :)

Comment: Nicely done. If you addtionally could describe (in spoiler tags) the individual logical deduction steps you've used, it would be worth addtional upvotes. :c)

Comment: Sure, I'm working on it ;)

Comment: Looking forward to the rest of the explanation! :) I'll give the tick once it's done.

Comment: @BmyGuest,boboquack Sorry for the delay, I was a bit busy yesterday. Hope you understand my step-by-step explanation. Feel free to ask if something is unclear or wrong (I hope it's not).

Comment: You can use the checkerboard colouring argument more efficiently, by counting the colours of cells that enter/exit a region, to show that a Mobius move at both a and c would lead to a parity error, without having to do any look-ahead deduction. Likewise, you can use a similar thing on the "8 squares inside the red frame" part as well.